# Powershell Comparing Array Elements

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm likely missing something simple here, so I apologize in advance.  I am also aware that there is likely a better approach to this, so I'm open to that as well.

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script that will look at an array of values, comparing them to see the value of the difference between two elements of an array.

Below is a sample data set I'm using to test with that is imported into powershell from CSV:

```
1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.7, 2.9, 3.0
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is running through this list and comparing the second entry with the first, the third with the second, fourth with the third, etc, adding the element to `$export` ONLY if it has a value that is at least 0.2 greater than the previous element.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$import = get-content C:/pathtoCSVfile
$count = $import.Length-1;
$current=0;

Do 
{    
    $current=$current+1;
    $previous=$current-1

    if (($import[$current]-$import[$previous]) -ge 0.2)
    {
        $export=$export+$import[$current]+"`r`n";
    }
} 
until ($current -eq $count)
```

Now I've run this with Trace on and it assigns values to `$current` and `$previous` and runs the subtraction of the two as described in the `if` condition on each loop through, but ONLY for the value of 2.7 (`$import[14]-$import[13]`) is it registering that the if condition has been met, thus leaving only a single value of 2.7 in `$export`.  I expected other values (1.7, 1.9, and 2.9) to also be added to the `$export` variable.

Again, this is probably something stupid/obvious I'm overlooking, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer.

Comment: Is $export a scalar value or an array? Define `$export = @()` if it is an array.

Comment: A core problem is that $import is a string and not an array.

Comment: @lit: Unless `C:/pathtoCSVfile` happens to contain just _1_ line, the output from `get-content C:/pathtoCSVfile` _is_ an array (of lines). As written, `$export` builds up a single, multi-line `[string]` instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that **decimal fractions have no *exact* representation in the implicitly used [`[double]` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=system.double), resulting in *rounding errors* that cause your `-ge 0.2` comparison to yield unexpected results**.

A simple example with `[double]` values, which are what PowerShell implicitly uses with number literals that have a decimal point:

```
PS> 2.7 - 2.5 -ge 0.2
True  # OK, but only accidentally so, due to the specific input numbers.

PS> 1.7 - 1.5 -ge 0.2
False  # !! Due to the inexact internally binary [double] representation.
```

---

If you force your calculations to **use the [`[decimal]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead**, the problem goes away.

Applied to the above example (appending `d` to a number literal in PowerShell makes it a `[decimal]`):

```
PS> 1.7d - 1.5d -ge 0.2d
True # OK - Comparison is now exact, due to [decimal] values.
```

Applied in the context of a more PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation of your code:

```
# Sample input; note that floating-point number literals such as 1.0 default to [double]
# Similarly, performing arithmetic on *strings* that look like floating-point numbers
# defaults to [double], and Import-Csv always creates string properties.
$numbers = 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.7, 2.9, 3.0

# Collect those array elements that are >= 0.2 than their preceding element
# in output *array* $exports.
$exports = foreach ($ndx in 1..($numbers.Count - 1)) {
  if ([decimal] $numbers[$ndx] - [decimal] $numbers[$ndx-1] -ge 0.2d) {
    $numbers[$ndx] 
  }
}

# Output the result array.
# To create a multi-line string representation, use $exports -join "`r`n"
$exports
```

The above yields:

```
1.7
1.9
2.7
2.9
```